# Does it make sense to use a personal Amazon Cloud Drive to host an SVN repository?

Tags: svn

I have 5GB of free storage on Amazon's Cloud Drive service that I'm not using, so I'm wondering: is it possible to create an SVN repository and be able to commit/update through TortoiseSVN?

I have an account at Assembla.com and use it for all my personal/school projects and love it, but Assembla has a 2GB limit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2gb is a ton of code, what are you storing in there? Have you considered alternate SVN hosts? Or upgrading to something more modern like Mercurial on bitbucket (unlimited private repos, TortiseHg is arguably better than TortiseSVN).

I'm not sure if Amazon is even capable of what you want to store from a technical sense, but my general experience with SVN and local network shares was pretty poor. I suspect something in the cloud will be nearly impossible to use.

Answer (score 1):

If you can access this cloud drive as a regular system, yes you can. In addition to checking out repositories using https, svn+ssh etc., you can use file URLs.

Comment: But how is the performance for file urls? SVN is very chatty . . .

Answer (score 1):

Amazon Cloud Drive is based on [Amazon S3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_S3). The problem with S3 is that it's designed for hosting of media files. Only reading predetermined file  has speed anything close to decent, any other file operations (including listing directories and changing permissions) are extremely slow.

I'm afraid SVN hosted in such a way would be so slow, that it would be completely unusable.